# The set $F_1\subset X_1$ is closed set in $X_1$ if and only if there is an closed set $F$ in $X$ such that $F\cap X_1=F_1$

Tags: metric-spaces

I need th proving this theorem:

*Let $(X, d)$ is metric space and let $(X_1, d_1)$ is its subspace. The set $G_1\subset X_1$ is open set in $X_1$ if and only if there is an open set $G$ in $X$ such that $G\cap X_1=G_1$. The set $F_1\subset X_1$ is closed set in $X_1$ if and only if there is an closed set $F$ in $X$ such that $F\cap X_1=F_1$.*

Prove: First part of the theorem I've proved i.e. (The set $G_1\subset X_1$ is open set in $X_1$ if and only if there is an open set $G$ in $X$ such that $G\cap X_1=G_1$.)

**But I do not know how to prove the second part of the theorem** (The set $F_1\subset X_1$ is closed set in $X_1$ if and only if there is an closed set $F$ in $X$ such that $F\cap X_1=F_1$).

Please if anyone can help me to prove the second part of the theorem, thank you, for your help and your attention

Comment: $F_1$ is closed in $X_1$ if and only if $X_1\setminus F_1$ is open in $X_1$.

Comment: yes i now the definition a when a subset closed, but i didnt now how to prove the second part of this theorem, but detailed

Comment: That wasn't meant as citing the definition, but as a hint on how to prove it.

Comment: Yeah, okay sorry sir, if you please detelano tell me how it proves that interests me, thank you

Comment: If $X_1 \cap G = (X_1 \setminus F_1)$, then what is $X_1 \cap (X\setminus G)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So $\;F_1\subset X\;$ is closed in $\;X_1\;$ iff $\;X\setminus F_1\;$ is open iff there exists open $\;G\subset X\;$ s.t.

$$(X\setminus F_1)\cap G\;\;\text{is open}\iff X\setminus\left((X\setminus F_1)\cap G\right)\stackrel{\text{de Morgan}}=\left(F_1\right)\cup\left(X\setminus G\right)\;\;\text{is closed}$$

(since $\;X\setminus(X\setminus F_1)=F_1\;$ ) , and we're done since trivially

$$F_1=F_1\cap\left[\left(F_1\right)\cup\left(X\setminus G\right)\right] $$

Comment: writing that should be used the De Morgan`s formula, whether this is a complete solution, thank you

Comment: @MadritZhaku, after reading your comment three times, I still have no idea what you tried to convey to me...

Comment: Sorry, just wanted to know if your solution is complete and should be continued but I'm sure your solution is a complete and thank you very much

Comment: Oh, ok @MadritZhaku, but that's a weird question since then it seems to be you didn't understand completely the solution (as then you'd see it is complete)...